# org.jgap.* does not include everything

Tags: java, import, libraries

I just tried to implement the JGAP Framework to my project and somehow I'm wondering about the following:

When I type `import org.jgap.*`, the class `MaxFuction` is not available somehow, but when I type `import.org.jgap.impl.job.MaxFunction` it is working. Do I understand something wrong with the `*`? I thought it includes every sub-"files" then, so normally `MaxFunction` should be included too, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing a `*` imports any class immediately inside the package, it does **not** recurse to subpackages. You could, of course, import using `*` from the subpackages too:

```
import.org.jgap.impl.job.*;
import.org.jgap.*;
```

Comment: Okay, and there's no way to implement the whole package recursively?

Comment: @user5638730 No. Packages in Java aren't really hierarchical, as explained in [the tutorail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) - scroll down to the "Apparent Hierarchies of Packages" section.